# The number of permutations with no fixed point minus the number of permutations with exactly one fixed point, is $\pm1$

Tags: combinatorics

If $f_n$ is the number of permutations of numbers $1$ to $n$ that no number is in it's place(I think same as $D_n$)and $g_n$ is the number of the same permutations with exactly one number in it's place Prove that $\mid f_n-g_n \mid =1$.

I need a proof using mosly combinatorics not mostly algebra.I think we should find sth like below:

$f_n-g_n=g_{n-1}-f_{n-1}$

But I can't do that.

Comment: What is the meaning of "no number in its place" and by "exactly one number in its place". Am sorry I'm just trying to understand your question!

Comment: $g_n = f_{ n-1 }$ is probably a good place to start.

Comment: To reformulate the question : A fix point of a permutation $\sigma_n$ is a number $j$ with $\sigma(j)=j$. The object is to prove that the number of permutations $\sigma_n$ with no fix point differs exactly one from the number of permutations $\sigma_n$ with exactly one fix point.

Comment: @PaulAljabar Hmm... You mean, $g_n=nf_{n-1}$?

Comment: @Taha What did you try?

Comment: @Did I tried to find a recurrence relation using $f_n$ and $g_n$ so that by subtracting them we get $f_n-g_n=g_{n-1}-f_{n-1}$

Comment: @Did yes, my bad ...

Comment: @PaulAljabar How did you get that relation?

Comment: @TahaAkbari Just fix one of the $n$ points ($n$ possibilities) and let the other $n-1$ points be deranged ($f_{n-1}$ possibilities). That gives $g_{n}=nf_{n-1}$.

Comment: On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Counting_derangements) you find that $!n=n[!(n-1)]+(-1)^n$, but a proof of that lacks.

Comment: Don't we have g_n >= f_n? Why the absolute difference then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *[rencontres numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers)* $D_n$ satisfy the recursion
$$D_n=(n-1)(D_{n-1}+D_{n-2})\ ,\tag{1}$$
which can be proven as follows: You obtain a derangement  $\pi\in{\cal S}_n$ by picking a derangement $\pi'\in{\cal S}_{n-1}$ and writing the entry $n$ at an arbitrary place in the cycle representation of $\pi'$, or by choosing a $k\in[n-1]$ and adding the transposition $(n,k)$ to a derangement of $[n-1]\setminus\{k\}$.

From $(1)$ one easily deduces
$$D_n-nD_{n-1}=-\bigl(D_{n-1}-(n-1)D_{n-2}\bigr)=\ldots=(-1)^n\ .$$
This should solve your problem.

Comment: "rencontres" > "dérangements".

Comment: What is $\Psi$?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be part of the way to a solution

Assuming that
$$
g_{n} = n f_{n-1}
$$

Use one of the recurrence relations for derangements:
$$
f_{n} = n f_{n-1} + (-1)^{n}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
f_{n} - g_{n}
&=
f_{n} - n f_{n-1}
\\
&=
f_{n} - n (n-1) f_{n-2} - n (-1)^{n-1}
\\
&=
f_{n} - n g_{n-1} - n(-1)^{n-1}
\\
&=
n f_{n-1} + (-1)^{n} - n g_{n-1} - n(-1)^{n-1}
\\
&=
n (f_{n-1} -  g_{n-1} - (-1)^{n-1}) +  (-1)^{n}  
\end{aligned}
$$

So we get

$$
\begin{aligned}
f_{n} - g_{n} - (-1)^{n} 
&=
n (f_{n-1} -  g_{n-1} - (-1)^{n-1}) 
\end{aligned}
$$

So we get a recurrence relation on the expression $d_{n} := f_{n} - g_{n} - (-1)^{n}$

Can't figure out where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Counting_derangements) we can prove with inclusion/exclusion that:
$$!n=n!\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$

The RHS can also be written as:$$n\left[(n-1)!\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\right]+(-1)^n=n\left[!(n-1)\right]+(-1)^n$$

Here $f_n=!n$ and as suggested in the comments $g_n=nf_{n-1}=n[!(n-1)]$.

This proves that $f_n-g_n=(-1)^n$ and consequently $|f_n-g_n|=1$.

Comment: This is an algebric proof rather than a combinatorial one.

Comment: @TahaAkbari I admit. Actually I did not read the question properly. Shame on me.